# How users can logout/delete his account from google spread sheet database using javascript when the user click there delete buttton on account.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sheets

Hi guys please am stuck on this code, need assistance, so I have created the spread sheet table called register and created 2 tables email and username and then put in the javascript code in google sheet app script and deployed it as control authority myself and view access as anyone, then I created the index.html as the register page so that if a user register they will be redirect to the home page, but which worked but then the code is not working for user to be able to delete there account instead they will just be redirected and then there data isnt deleted from the google spread sheet table database, so please help me rectify this code I will list all the code so that you can really under and help me rectify/debug the issue, so this is how the url and keys for spreadsheet look like

spread shit id and url
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OGlLMH9-Oe62654TGHJ7p-jNrjm765RFRv3j_q0Sc/edit#gid=0
sharable link   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OG76545H9-Oe6YT67aK-MIxER97p-jN658TfRv3j_q0Sc/edit?usp=sharing

Deployment successfully updated for google sheet web script.
Version 1 on Mar 29, 2024, 4:32?AM
Deployment ID
AKfycbwoq52h_V1HJNZZhV7765ERTYUY56yTOFXmK8shPJb1wve4UZ0V9Tw
Web app
URL
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfy344352h_V1H456787654567HGTYaGSObIsSOl2yTOFXmK8shPJb1wve4UZ0V9Tw/exec
Please note that this isnt my real details but exactly how it will look

So this is the index.html register page code that when they register they will be redirected to a home page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Registration Form</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <style>
        body {
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
        }
        .container {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        #register-box {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }
        #error-message {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        </style>
    </head> 



<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="register-box">
    <h2 class="text-center mb-4">Register</h2>
    <div id="error-message" class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert"></div>
    <form id="registration-form">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registration-form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var username = $('#username').val();
        
        $.ajax({
        url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwoq52h_V1HJNZ8765678HoT1vWZYaGSObIsSOl7654567HhPJb1wve4UZ0V9Tw/exec',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: email,
            username: username
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response === 'Success') {
            alert('Registration successful!');
            window.location.href = 'home.html'; // Redirect to home page
            } else {
            $('#error-message').text('Registration failed. Please try again.').removeClass('d-none');
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#error-message').text('Registration failed. Please try again.').removeClass('d-none');
        }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

so they are redirected but once they go to account.html page which contains that users email and username be displayed and a delete button below

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>User Account</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <style>
        /* Add your custom CSS styles here */
        body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .container {
        margin-top: 50px;
        }

        .user-details {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>User Details</h2>
    <div class="user-details">
    <p>Email: <span id="user-email"></span></p>
    <p>Username: <span id="user-username"></span></p>
    </div>
    <button id="delete-btn" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Account</button>
</div>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'></script>
<script>
    // Function to fetch user details from the server
    function fetchUserDetails() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwoq52h_V1HJNZZhV79876aGSObIsSOl2yTOFXmK8s876e4UZ0V9Tw/exec',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
        $('#user-email').text(data.email);
        $('#user-username').text(data.username);
        },
        error: function () {
        alert('Error fetching user details');
        }
    });
    }

// Function to delete user account
    function deleteUser() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwoq52h_V1H87654ERTUIU7652yTOFXmK8shPJb764UZ0V9Tw/exec',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
        deleteEmail: $('#user-email').text()
        },
        success: function () {
        alert('Account deleted successfully');
        window.location.href = 'index.html'; // Redirect to registration page
        },
        error: function () {
        alert('Error deleting account');
        }
    });
    }

    // Fetch user details when the page loads
    $(document).ready(function () {
    fetchUserDetails();
    });

    // Attach click event to delete button
    $('#delete-btn').click(function () {
    deleteUser();
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>


    Now here is the app script code that runs in google spread sheet app script that allow registration and delete of the data i really dont know which one has the issue so please help me rectify this guys, its really giving me a hard time, here is the appsscript function

    function doPost(e) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1OGHGMH9-Oe8767K-MIxER97p-jNrj987fRv3j_q0Sc').getActiveSheet();
    
    // Check if the request is for registration or deletion
    if (e.parameter.hasOwnProperty('email')) {
        // Registration request
        var email = e.parameter.email;
        var username = e.parameter.username;
        
        // Check if the email or username already exists
        var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][0] == email || data[i][1] == username) {
            return ContentService.createTextOutput('User already exists');
        }
        }
        
        // If the user doesn't exist, append the row
        sheet.appendRow([email, username]);
        
        return ContentService.createTextOutput('User registered successfully');
    } else if (e.parameter.hasOwnProperty('deleteEmail')) {
        // Deletion request
        var emailToDelete = e.parameter.deleteEmail;
        
        // Find the row with the email to delete
        var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        var rowIndexToDelete = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][0] == emailToDelete) { // Assuming email is in the first column
            rowIndexToDelete = i + 1; // Adding 1 because sheets are 1-indexed
            break;
        }
        }
        
        if (rowIndexToDelete !== -1) {
        sheet.deleteRow(rowIndexToDelete); // Delete the row if found
        return ContentService.createTextOutput('User details deleted successfully');
        } else {
        return ContentService.createTextOutput('User not found');
        }
    } else {
        return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid request');
    }
    }



    please who can help me rectify this, I am coding it with javascript for cordova app.
```

Comment: Please someone should help me out of this pickle really appreciate in advance.

Comment: Please someone should assist me with this, anyone.

Comment: Can't someone wise from stack help me debug this, please I really need help.